# Qual a maneira correta de implementar filtros em Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filtro

Bom dia!

Atualmente, tenho uma aplicação com um simples CRUD, e estou criando uma nova view para exibir os registros. Nessa view, estou incluindo alguns filtros que são links com parâmetros para serem enviados ao controller e filtrar a lista com esses registros.
A minha dúvida é: qual a melhor maneira ( mais inteligente ) de se criar filtro no Rail?

Segue como está implementado:

Na view **Principal**, temos uma coluna com os registros e uma coluna com os filtros:

- view / controller-action / path  
  index.html.erb / ondeEstamos#index / onde-estamos
- Para criar um filtro, eu crio uma rota nova (ex: onde-estamos/filtros/:f ), crio uma nova função que vai pegar esse parâmetro, e reaproveito a view principal.

Então fica algo assim:

**Controller:**

```
def index

end

def index_filtro
    "Aqui os registros nao filrados através de uma nova query incluindo o parâmetro enviado pela view"
    render index
end
```

**Routes:**

```
get '/onde-estamos', to: 'onde#index', as: 'onde-estamos'
get '/onde-estamos/filtros/:f', to: 'onde#index-filtro', as: 'onde-estamos-filtro'
```

Isso funciona, mas não acredito que essa seja a melhor maneira.
Essa solução me impede de ser mais flexível com os filtros, como por exemplo, combinar filtros e etc.
`

Comment: Envia uma requisão para a rota index mesmo com os parâmetros enviados por query parameter: /onde-estamos?filtro_1=valor&filtro_2=valor2.

Comment: Vou refatorar assim! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, acho que o ideal seria utilizar [Filter Scope](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments)

Um exemplo de utilização:

seu Model:

```
class Dinosaur < ActiveRecord::Base
 scope :with_name, lambda {|parameter| where("name like ?", "%#{parameter}%")}     
 scope :taller_than, lambda {|parameter| where("height > ?", parameter)}

 def self.search(parameters)
   dinosaur_query = self.scoped
   parameters.each do |parameter, value|
     if not value.empty? and dinosaur_query.respond_to? parameter
       dinosaur_query = dinosaur_query.send(parameter, value) 
     end
   end
   dinosaur_query
 end
end
```

seu Controller:

```
@dinosaurs = Dinosaur.search(params)
```

Comment: Obrigado Geilton. Dei uma estudada e acabei encontrando os filters Scope. Vou unir com a solução para as rotas enviada pelo Matheus SIlva.